# Integration of a rational function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve the following rational integral (I got assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392294/integration-of-a-rational-function-from-infinity)):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{a+x}{b^2 + (a+x)^2}\frac{1}{1+c(a-x)^2}}dx$$
where $\{a, b, c\}\in \mathbb{R}$. I would like also to find an analytical solution using Mathematica. I have tried `Integrate`,

```
Integrate[(a + x)/(b^2 + (a + x)^2)*1/(
  1 + c*(a - x)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

but this gives me an imaginary result based on $a$, $b$ and $c$. I believe the result should be 100% real.

Am I using `Integrate` the correct way?

Comment: "I believe the result should be 100% real." - no doubt, but you should know that sometimes *Mathematica*, out of convenience, expresses real results using complex numbers, somewhat similar to expressing the sine as complex exponentials. Anyway, have you seen `Assuming[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I'll take a look at it and let you know how it turns out, thanks.

Comment: ...or the `Assumptions` option to `Integrate`? `Assumptions -> {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, c ∈ Reals}` would probably work.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). *Implicitly* assuming $b\gt 0$ (WLG) and $c\gt 0$, we may (very quickly) obtain the solution as `2 \[Pi] I  Sum[Residue[(a + x)/((b^2 + (a + x)^2) (1 + c (a - x)^2)), {x, z}], {z, {b I - a, I/Sqrt[c] + a}}] // Simplify`, yielding $\frac{2 a \sqrt{c} \pi }{1+2 b \sqrt{c}+4 a^2 c+b^2 c}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Integrate[(a + x)/((b^2 + (a + x)^2) (1 + c*(a - x)^2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, c ∈ Reals, b != 0, c > 0}]
```

Which gives:

```
(-4 a b^2 c π + 2 a Sqrt[c] (1 + 4 a^2 c + b^2 c) π Abs[b])/
(Abs[b] + c (8 a^2 - 2 b^2 + (4 a^2 + b^2)^2 c) Abs[b])
```

Note that I've added additional assumptions so that *Mathematica* doesn't return the result as a `ConditionalExpression`.